# Dividing the gradient in Tensorflow by a value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to divide the gradient in Tensorflow by a value (e.g., 5) for bias correction purposes. I can compute and apply the gradient as follows

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
gradient,var = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(cost))
newgradient = #Not sure how to implement gradient/5
train_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(newgradient , var))
```

where cost is the error function to be minimized. I don't know how to divide each element in gradient by 5 (I guess shape of the gradient depends on number of layers and number of neurons per each layer).

Thanks

Comment: Ask your question just once, and please be patient. I assure a lot of folks from the Tensorflow team take a look at the tensorflow tag at least once a day.

Comment: why not `newgradient = [g/5 for g in gradient]`? I tried with a simple example and it works fine.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried; It results in this error `TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled` when I use optimizer.apply_gradients

Comment: Then, you `gradient` must be `Tensor` and not a list of tensors (since you can't iterate over it). If so, just do `newgradient = gradient/5`.